# Getting Fade Transition To Work In Live Environment

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this to work in a live environment: http://jsfiddle.net/LREwC/

Here's the test HTML page I set up:

```
<head>
<title>1</title>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
<p class="quotes">first quote</p>
<p class="quotes">second quote</p>
<p class="quotes">third quote</p>
</body>
```

For some reason it's not working in a live environment, but it works fine in JSfiddle. Am I doing something wrong with publishing the code?

The CSS and JS script files are linked properly. I tested the link live, I just shortened it so it didn't link to the site I'm working on.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: check for errors in your browser's developer tools console tab..and make sure the link to your js file is correct

Comment: Is that a typo? It should be `$(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for all dom elements to be ready:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

});
```

Another option would be to move your script to the end of your document.